# How to display categories as titles on my page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type named "State Leagues" using types plugin. My post type has some categories and outputs both. When I display the posts' titles it displays correctly. My code for displaying post titles is this:

```
 <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'stateleague-pos-type',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'order_by' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            );
             $loop = new WP_Query($args);
//            $counter = 0;
//            $big = 1;
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
          ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

               <h1> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
                </a>  
?>
```

Now I want to display the categories' names as the title instead of the posts' titles. I have searched for it but didn't find anything that works. Is it possible to display category names as titles?

Comment: do you want page title or category title

Comment: i want categories to display as title ...

Comment: in this code where is your category name/slug

Comment: i have just created categories i dont know how should i pass the slug and where?

Comment: oky no problem i alredy give you the code please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $taxonomy = 'filters';
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
    ?>

        <ul>
            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;?>



Or in fuctions.php Put  this:



  function get_the_category_custompost( $id = false, $tcat = 'category' ) {
    $categories = get_the_terms( $id, $tcat );
    if ( ! $categories )
        $categories = array();

    $categories = array_values( $categories );

    foreach ( array_keys( $categories ) as $key ) {
        _make_cat_compat( $categories[$key] );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'get_the_categories', $categories );
}


and call the function as:



<?php $cat = get_the_category_custompost($post->ID, 'Your Custom Taxonomy'); ?>
```

Try this i hope it will help

Comment: it is giving this error : Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /var/www/camden-tiger/wp-content/themes/camden/functions.php on line 987 Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/camden-tiger/wp-content/themes/camden/functions.php on line 989 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/camden-tiger/wp-content/themes/camden/functions.php on line 989

Comment: are you change the filter from  $taxonomy = 'filters';

Comment: i havenot changed anything